# Request method 'PATCH' not supported

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a profile update page which is supposed to show errors on the fields.
However, when I remove the value from an input field instead of getting an error below, I get 405 - `Request method 'PATCH' not supported`.
I have no idea what could be the problem, any advice is appreciated.

```html
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
@GetMapping("/profile/update/{id}")
    public String showUpdateForm(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        ProfileUpdateServiceModel profileServiceModel = this.userService.getProfileUpdateServiceModelById(id);
        ProfileUpdateBindingModel profileUpdateBindingModel = this.mapper.map(profileServiceModel, ProfileUpdateBindingModel.class);
        if (!model.containsAttribute("profileUpdateBindingModel")) {
            model.addAttribute("profileUpdateBindingModel", profileUpdateBindingModel);
        }
//        model.addAttribute("profileUpdateBindingModel", profileUpdateBindingModel);
        return "update-profile";
    }

    @PatchMapping("/profile/update/{id}")
    public String update(@PathVariable("id") Long id,
                         @Valid ProfileUpdateBindingModel profileUpdateBindingModel,
                         BindingResult br,
                         RedirectAttributes rAtt) {

        if (br.hasErrors()) {
            rAtt
                    .addFlashAttribute("profileUpdateBindingModel", profileUpdateBindingModel)
                    .addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.profileUpdateBindingModel", br);
            return "redirect:/users/profile/update/" + id;
        }
        return "profile";
    }
```

profile.html:

```html
<form
   th:method="GET"
   th:action="@{/users/profile/update/{id}(id=${session.currentUserId})}">
```

update-profile.html:

```html
<form
   th:action="@{/users/profile/update/{id}(id=*{userId})}"
   th:method="PATCH"
   th:object="${profileUpdateBindingModel}"
   enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="col-sm-6">
   <label class="label-align">First Name<span
      class="required">*</span></label>
   <input
      th:field="*{firstName}"
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      name="name"/>
   <div class="col-auto">
      <small th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}"
         th:errors="*{firstName}"
         id="first-nameError"
         class="text-light form-text bg-danger rounded">xxx</small>
   </div>
</div>
```

LOGS:

```html
2022-03-06 11:57:45.050 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2022-03-06 11:57:45.077 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2022-03-06 11:57:45.131 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/css/style.css", parameters={}
2022-03-06 11:57:45.131 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [static/], ServletContext [/]]
2022-03-06 11:57:45.135 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2022-03-06 11:57:45.138 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/images/undraw_profile_1.svg", parameters={}
2022-03-06 11:57:45.138 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [static/], ServletContext [/]]
2022-03-06 11:57:45.138 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2022-03-06 11:57:45.168 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/images/1915.jpg", parameters={}
2022-03-06 11:57:45.169 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [static/], ServletContext [/]]
2022-03-06 11:57:45.178 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2022-03-06 11:57:59.981 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : PATCH "/users/profile/update/", parameters={multipart}
2022-03-06 11:57:59.984  WARN 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PATCH' not supported]
2022-03-06 11:57:59.984 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
2022-03-06 11:57:59.986 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={multipart}
2022-03-06 11:57:59.986 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2022-03-06 11:57:59.995 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2022-03-06 11:58:00.022 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 405
2022-03-06 11:58:00.077 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/css/style.css", parameters={}
2022-03-06 11:58:00.078 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [static/], ServletContext [/]]
2022-03-06 11:58:00.083 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2022-03-06 11:58:00.132 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/images/undraw_profile_1.svg", parameters={}
2022-03-06 11:58:00.134 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [static/], ServletContext [/]]
2022-03-06 11:58:00.137 DEBUG 9492 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Code 405 means `Method not Allowed`. In your spring you are mentioning `GET` method but in your Form you are mentioning to submit a `PATCH` method.

Change your  form to

```
<form
   th:action="@{/users/profile/update/{id}(id=*{userId})}"
   th:method="GET"
   th:object="${profileUpdateBindingModel}"
   enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I have updated the post - in profile.html I have GET to show the update page , then in update-profile I have PATCH  to make the actual update and this is when I get the error.

Comment: @sjs can you enable add logs as well? `Method not supported-405` is a very vague exception. you can enable debug logs by adding `logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG` as well and add it here

Comment: I added Logs + profileBindingModel + imageBindingModel + Thymeleaf for the image part.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the pathvariable like this :

@PathVariable Long id

or like this ::

@PatchMapping(params = "/{id}", consumes = "application/json")

Answer (score 0):

I am not confident about thymeleaf, but you can check this syntax[in second html page]:

```
th:action="@{/users/profile/update/{id}(id=*{userId})}"
```

As in your home.html form, you have assigned the value using `$` sign but here it is in `*`.

Also, make sure your forms are enclosed properly with `</form>` tags.